# ngOnInit called many times in all inheritance classes in Angular 5

Tags: angular, class, inheritance, duplicates

I use import {Ng2StateDeclaration} from '@uirouter/angular';
And I'm facing a problem now in Angular 5
I have Paper class with no template:

```
export class Paper implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
     // async function here
     this.loadData();
   }
```

}

Now I have another class called PaperEdit:

```
export class PaperEdit extends Paper{
  constructor(){super();}
}
```

In PaperEdit class, I have many parts with long html:
paper-edit.html

```
<paper-edit-form-1></paper-edit-form-1>
<paper-edit-form-2></paper-edit-form-2>
<paper-edit-form-3></paper-edit-form-3>
```

PaperEditForm1,2,3 is a class with only html files, no logic, I want inherit all variables and functions from Paper class like PaperEdit

```
export class PaperEditForm1 extends Paper {
  constructor(){super();}
  // no function here`
```

}

And result is: ngOnInit of Paper class run 4 times, it means this.loadData() run 4 times too. 
So any methods to prevent this issues, I want that lifecycle only run 1 time! Thanks.

Comment: You can't have the life-cycle of 4 components only run once. So this question makes no sense.

Comment: @cgTag: Yes. i'm using `import {Ng2StateDeclaration} from '@uirouter/angular';`. Which mean in url: edit/view page, I will load Paper component firstly. this component has empty style. If in url: '/edit+ id', I will load PaperEdit component

Comment: I don't see how your question relates to routing?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar issue like this.Instead of inheriting Paper class in PaperEditForm1 class,just make the function **loadData static**.Import the Paper class in the child PaperEditForm1 class.Now,just call the loadData static function using **Paper.loadData()**.This minimizes the constructor call and **removes the inheritance**.It makes call only when needed.This solved my case.

Comment: Thanks for great idea. But I have many PaperEditForm classes, so will I call  Paper.loadData() 3 times in 3 child classes here?

Comment: Yes,You need to write Paper.loadData() in each of the classes you need to inherit the functionality.This may increase the code length,but,concisely increases the performance too.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved issue by following your method :)